# Right click menu option remove windows 10

Tags: windows, right-click

Hotheadedly I have installed a duplicate removal program and now, every time when I use the right click menu, I have another option `Scan with CloneFilesChecker` which doesn't work anyway. The program was useless and uninstalled, but I can't find a way to get rid of that extra bit.

Is anyone able to advise? I have tried the ways commented on here but can't find that extension to disable it.

[image: menu bug]

Comment: 1) What "duplicate removal program" did you install and why? 2) Use clear language and punctuation, ellipses indicate a thought is continuing, but it seems you're using them instead of periods. Just use periods. 3) What things have you tried and what extension are you looking for. Use the EDIT button to improve your question please, and add details and specific things you have done, so we know what not to suggest, and better understand the problem you are having.

Comment: @radu - You should spend some more time making sure the question is the clearest it can be. You probably just want to use `ShellMenuView` or `ShellExtView` from Microsoft to remove the invalid context menu item.

Comment: ive tried , but seems to find the extension to deactivate it